# Getting underfined when calling API

Tags: javascript, html, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a website which is being hosted through amplify (AWS) in which im trying to gather the user input, store it and send it though the API gateway.

Below is the scrpit and button

```js
var callAPI = (unit1, unit2, wcka, unit3, unit4, scka) => {
  // instantiate a headers object
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  // add content type header to object
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  // using built in JSON utility package turn object to string and store in a variable
  var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "unit1": unit1,
    "unit2": unit2,
    "wcka": wcka,
    "unit3": unit3,
    "unit4": unit4,
    "scka": scka
  });
  // create a JSON object with parameters for API call and store in a variable
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  // make API call with parameters and use promises to get response
  fetch("https://0vuhroulyh.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/dev", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => alert(JSON.parse(result).body))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="callAPI(document.getElementById('unit1').value,document.getElementById('unit2').value,document.getElementById('wcka').value,document.getElementById('unit3').value,document.getElementById('unit4').value,document.getElementById('scka').value)">CALCULATE</button>
```

Any ideas anyone?

I've tried gathering the values within the variable instead of the button, having another function which stores teh values then lead onto the variable

But no luck.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Where is the HTML which contains elements with id `unit1`, `unit2`, etc.? Please show a [mre].

Comment: Well, I'd start with opening the aws console, navigating to the aws api gateway and checking if you're calling the right URL. The one you've specified here, looks like it leads to the very route of the api gateway, and I'm pretty sure there's some additional path required, like /dev/functionname.

Comment: the HTML form section is below:    <div class="inputForm">
   <form>
    <div class="row">
     <label for="unit1" id="gradeHead">Unit 1:</label>
       <input type="text" id="unit1" name="unit1" placeholder="/50">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <label for="unit2" id="gradeHead">Unit 2:</label>
       <input type="text" id="unit2" name="unit2" placeholder="/50">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <label for="wcka" id="gradeHead">Winter CKA:</label>
       <input type="text" id="wcka" name="wcka" placeholder="/75">
      </div>

Comment: I noticed the provided code snippet seems to be missing the HTML elements for #unit3, #unit4 and #scka.  The button's onclick method is trying to get those values and failing.  It's not even getting to the part where it calls the API.